# VAST 2/3 provider

Tags: vast

I wonder do you know where I can quickly register and get different VAST 2/3 feeds? I need to add VAST/VPAID support to a video player and I'm looking for an example feeds.

I see that IAB have for VAST2, but not for vast 3. http://www.iab.net/guidelines/508676/digitalvideo/vast/vast_xml_samples

I requested registration from https://www.google.com/doubleclick/publishers/index.html but still waiting for 2 days :(

Thanks for

Answer (score 3):

Forget DC as sample feed, there is no one actually, becayse all the creatives are objects of licensing, here some links with VAST 2.0 XML examples:

http://demo.tremorvideo.com/proddev/vast/vast_inline_linear.xml
http://demo.tremorvideo.com/proddev/vast/vast_wrapper_linear_2.xml
https://github.com/dailymotion/vast-client-js/tree/master/test (Some sample XMLs)
https://github.com/theonion/videojs-vast-plugin/blob/master/spec/sample-vast.xml

Actually if you surf GitHub you'll find out that there is pretty decent amount of VAST 2/3 XMLs .